# amazon ec2 micro RHEL: how to install nginx or others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I chose micro free RHEL6.4 instance  with EC2/Amazon, when I login, I found there no gcc, which I can yum install it. and there no nginx to yum install ? 
I must install gcc and develop tools and download nginx source code to install ? oh ,the free is only 30Gb one month?

Comment: I install from nginx source because I have no REEL account, and others

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation page inside [nginx website](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Prebuilt_Packages_for_Linux_and_BSD)